# Проверка на UTF-8

Tags: php

Привет.
Никак не знаю как сформолировать тему...
Насколько важно проверять кодировку данных пользователя?**
Увидел такое:

```
$utf8 = iconv(mb_detect_encoding($input), 'UTF-8', $input);
```

А такое защитит от XSS

```
htmlspecialchars($string, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
```

Что будет если символ вне кодировки засунуть в utf-8 БД?****И что на выходе при запросе с БД?**
Увидел проверку на UTF-8

```
function isUTF8($string) {
    return (utf8_encode(utf8_decode($string)) == $string);
}
```

Пишут что эта функция некорректно работает...Она работает только для символов  ISO-8859-1.Есть лучший аналог?

Как кодировать все в utf-8?

Comment: Какая-то из этих функций (`utf8_encode` и `utf8_decode`) может отвалится, если во входящих данных будут невалидные символы - это факт. Когда столкнулся с этим, в свое время решилось костылем.

Comment: а пример не припомните и как решили?

Comment: А вообще есть вот такая вещь: [`mb_detect_encoding()`][1]

  [1]: http://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.mb-detect-encoding.php

Comment: Если не ошибусь, то увидев, что страница выдана в браузер в некой кодировке, браузер должен возвращать данные в той же кодировке.  
Ни разу по крайней мере не видел, чтобы страница выдавалась в UTF8, а данные приходили в какой-то другой кодировке